# How can I resolve my uncaught syntax error?

Tags: reactjs

```
const { data: dataUser, isLoading: isLoadingUser, isError: isErrorUser } = useUser()
const { data, isLoading, isFetching, isError } = useCustomers(dataUser?.partnerId)
```

When I test my code I have an Unexpected token here

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use a JavaScript runtime that supports [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (see [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility)).

Comment: @jarmod all browser support it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the complete text of the error message that you get and what command(s), if any, you ran to get that output.

Comment: If you type `const xxx = {}; xxx?.yyy` into the JavaScript console of your browser dev tools and press enter, what happens? Uncaught SyntaxError or undefined?

Comment: I specifically asked for text, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: But apparently you use babel to transpile your JS. Have you checked if babel is configured to support that?

Comment: @JoachimSauer i just have a file with the cdn of babel, that's it

Comment: @jarmod I have undefined

Comment: OK, so your JS runtime supports it but however you're using babel doesn't.

Comment: @user10863293 no, that's not it. The error comes **out of the babel JS file** and not the browser itself. So **Babel** has problems parsing that code correctly somehow, which means you must look into what Babel does here and how to make it accept your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I change the version of my babel file (version : 7.21.2) and it works

Comment: Could you specify what version of Babel you were using, and what version you switched to?